# Error calling function from dictionary

Tags: python

I just want to create a class with a lot of functions which need to import some variables of the class for there output. To make the use more efficient i wanted to store the functions in a dictionary, but somehow that is not working at all...

---

```
class A(object):

    var = 'hello'
    def g(self,x):
        return self.var
    dict = {'g':g}


if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = A()
    print a.g(0)
    print a.dict['g'](0)
```

---

### OUTPUT

```
hello
    print a.dict['g'](0)
TypeError: g() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

---

what is happening within the dictionary with the function g???

Comment: When you say "more efficient", what are you comparing against?

Comment: I would suggest that you just write Python in the idiomatic way and avoid these "optimizations". You'll it won't help much, and may actually make is slow. Definitely less readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

When a function is called as a method, it implicitly gets the invocant as first argument. But that's not the case when you pull it out of the dict. You you'd have to call

```
print a.dict['g'](a, 0)
```

On a side note, I'd expect the call through dict to be slower, not faster, because you first need to get the dict from the object, which is itself basically equivalent to getting the method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jan Hudec's answer, you could also do without `dict` entirely by using the [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function, like so:

```
class A(object):

    var = 'hello'
    def g(self,x):
        return self.var


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print a.g(0)
    print getattr(a, 'g')(0)
```

With the advantage of keeping your classes clean.

Comment: Note, that `getattr` is *the* builtin function implementing member lookup. The two statements are exactly equivalent, but the later allows the member name to be a variable just like with the dict.